# iOS Swift CollectionView Cell are Cutting Down

Tags: ios, swift3, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

we are using `UICollectionView` for displaying some data's. My problem is when scrolling cell `horizontal` cell's are cutting down . How to fix it?

Here is my tried code:

```
func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int
{
   return 1
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat
{
   return 1.0
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat
{
   return 1.0
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView : UICollectionView,layout collectionViewLayout:UICollectionViewLayout,sizeForItemAt indexPath:IndexPath) -> CGSize
{
   let width = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
   return CGSize(width: width,height: collectionView.frame.size.height)
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets
{
    return UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)
    // top, left, bottom, right
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
   return 5
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
{
   let ViewSize = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
   let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CustomCell", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! CSDashboardCustomCell
   cell.MainView.frame = CGRect(x: 10, y: 10, width: ViewSize - 40, height: 142)
   cell.MainView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
   cell.MainView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
   cell.MainView.layer.shadowOpacity = 1
   cell.MainView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize.zero
   cell.MainView.layer.shadowRadius = 2
   cell.MainView.layer.cornerRadius = 6

   return cell
}
```

[image]

Comment: do you want to achieve card layout in which you can slide only one card at a time

Comment: No, need to show little view of next cell but need to show full view of current cell @RahulGUsai